# Typescript Angular2 - complaining about missing types

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I have the following code:

```
  var headers = new Headers();
                            // headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                            headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                            this.http.post(
                                'http://192.168.1.45:3000/testrestapi',
                                {headers: headers}
                            ).map((res => res.json())
        .subscribe(data => {
          // we've got back the raw data, now generate the core schedule data
          // and save the data for later reference
          this.data = data;
      console.log('Friends Provider was a success!');
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
          resolve(this.data);
        },
    (err)=>{
        console.log('Error in Friends Provider!');
    },
    ()=>{
           console.log('Friends Provider network call has ended!');
    }
        )

       )
   });
```

The code compiles fine without error, but I get the following errors in my ide:

[image]

I am following this docs: https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/http/Http-class.html . It shows how to use HTTP for GET, but not for POST. It seems I am missing the type for my headers which I am unsure what to put here as well it complains about the type for the subscribe method and again I am unsure what to put here as I am following the docs and it does not seem to have anything different?

Comment: is it complete code?

Comment: *compiles fine without error* and then you show a picture of compile errors? You import Http twice like the error says, for starters. Read the errors and fix the simplest ones at least first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have imported Http module 2 times in 2nd and 3rd lines of your code, one of them is redundant.

API for http post is:

```
post(url: string, body: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs) : Observable<Response>
```

in https://angular.io/api/http/Http

it expects a JSON.stringified body as the second parameter but you are pushing the header options which should be the third parameter.

I also suggest using

```
headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

instead of `append`.

Also you are missing the paranthesis in subscribe after data.

```
.subscribe(
    (data) => {
        console.log('Do something with data here \n',data);
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a reason why set is better than append?

Comment: Because if you use the method that your http request and header.append is in more than once, you will append the header 2 times :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 var headers = new Headers();
                            // headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
       headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
       this.http.post(
                       'http://192.168.1.45:3000/testrestapi',
                                {headers: headers}
                      )
        .map((res => res.json())
        .subscribe(data => 
         {

          this.data = data;
          console.log('Friends Provider was a success!');
          console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
          //resolve(this.data);
          },
        (err)=>{
        console.log('Error in Friends Provider!');
        },
        ()=>{
           console.log('Friends Provider network call has ended!');
        }

       );
```

Answer (score 0):

> The code compiles fine without error,

*Just because you get valid JavaScript* doesn't mean that it compiled without error. This is actually a TypeScript *feature* (see [why typescript](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/why-typescript.html)).

The errors you are seeing in the error are the compiler errrors